# Can I load data from RAM by using pointer to memory with physical addressing?

Tags: memory, linux-kernel, kernel, linux-device-driver, virtual-address-space

Can I load data from RAM by using pointer to memory with physical addressing(not to virtual) from my driver (Linux-kernel) without allocating pages (PDEs/PTEs) in virtual addressing?

Comment: What is *"CPU-RAM"*?  There's a CPU and there's RAM.  Do you mean processor cache memory?

Comment: @sawdust  No, I mean RAM :)

Comment: I'm not entirely sure if this is completely relevant to your question..
Give it a quick read if you can though..
http://www.tldp.org/LDP/khg/HyperNews/get/devices/addrxlate.html

Comment: @user1761555  Do I must to use 'ioremap()' to get virtual address in kernel space (allocate PDEs/PTEs) and get access to this memory by  virtual address, or can I read physical address directly? And how can I read memory directly by physical address?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes! "/dev/mem" is an image of physical memory, and you can even access this from user space.

For example, to access physical address `0x7000000`, the code below summarizes the steps:

```
fd = open("/dev/mem", O_RDWR);
map = mmap(NULL, SIZE, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, fd, 0x7000000);
```

Comment: Thanks! And if I have 8 GB RAM, and I do that you written, then will be created PDEs/PTEs in page table for 8GB of RAM, i.e. 2 millions of PTEs, isn't it?

Comment: Although theoretically possible, I think you want just to map a region of physical memory, and that region is of 'limited' size.

Comment: But in your example, we do not specify the size of the region, but only specify the starting address of the region - does that mean we are mapping all physical memory (8GB)?

Comment: The `/dev/mem` implementation will temporarily allocate virtual pages when you access it with `read`/`write`. With `mmap`, all pages will be allocated.

Comment: No, it does not always map all memory. In the example, the size of the mapping is specified in the variable SIZE. It is not explicity in the code. You can see details in the man page of mmap.